# Safari animation on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, safari, css-animations

I have page with form, that loads quite long after submit. That is why I decide to place spinner over button.

Instead if submit button I have div, that make:

```
$submit_btn.click(function(e){
    if ($submit_btn.attr("data-send") == "yes"){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    else {
        $('#reg').html('<div id="spin_reg" class="spinner-icon"></div>');
        $new_try_now.submit();
    }
});
```

In div spinner I have CSS3 animation.

Problem is that animation works well in Chrome, but in Safari it doesn't start.
I think the problem is that Safari kill all processes on page.

How I can avoid it without AJAX?

**Edit:**

Animation:

```
@-webkit-keyframes nprogress-spinner {
  0%   { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);   transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-moz-keyframes nprogress-spinner {
  0%   { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);   transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-o-keyframes nprogress-spinner {
  0%   { -o-transform: rotate(0deg);   transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -o-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-ms-keyframes nprogress-spinner {
  0%   { -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);   transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@keyframes nprogress-spinner {
  0%   { transform: rotate(0deg);   transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
.spinner-icon {
    display: block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;

    border: solid 2px transparent;
    border-top-color:  #158FD2;
    border-left-color: #158FD2;
    border-radius: 100%;

    -webkit-animation: nprogress-spinner 900ms linear infinite;
    -moz-animation:    nprogress-spinner 900ms linear infinite;
    -ms-animation:     nprogress-spinner 900ms linear infinite;
    -o-animation:      nprogress-spinner 900ms linear infinite;
    animation:         nprogress-spinner 900ms linear infinite;
}
```

Comment: you have show you `css` for animations so that we can tell you `safari` version of it.. :)

Comment: Very nice JavaScript, but don't you have troubles with animations? Please provide your css!

Comment: This _may_ be caused by a JS error. Nothing in the console ?

Comment: Apple says: 
You must set the `-webkit-animation-duration` and `-webkit-animation-name` properties in order to see an animation.

Try to use long declarations instead of only `-webkit-animation` for safari.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A bit late to answer this, but may still help somebody. :)

Safari stops running scripts/gifs and etc. after submit. You need to submit the form after the spinner is shown already.

```
$('#spinner').show(function() {
     $('#form').submit();
});
```

In my case `#spinner` was already rendered with `style='display:none'`.
If you don't want to render it before you need it, you can add `display:none` to your `#spin_reg` CSS, and then write JS like this:

```
$('#reg')
    .html('<div id="spin_reg" class="spinner-icon"></div>')
    .show(function() { $new_try_now.submit(); });
```